# What is the etymology of "itsy bitsy"?

Tags: etymology

Where did the phrase "itsy bitsy" come from?

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_Hungarian_origin),

> [It] is sometimes linked to Hungarian ici-pici ("tiny") by popular sources,
>   but is regarded as an unrelated English formation by English
>   dictionaries.

If it's not Hungarian in origin, how did it come about?

Comment: [The Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/word/itsy-bitsy) is considered a standard reference, and should always be referenced in questions about etymology where it comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *OED* traces the term back to a variant of ***little*** and ***bitty*** meaning "comprised of little bits."

**Bitty** is first attested in **1892**.

> It is an awful thing to be shut up for a week with all the ‘bitty’ papers of the day.

- *The Idler*

**Little bitsy** is attested in **1905**.

> They was little-bitsy fellers.

- *Dialect Notes*

And finally, **itsy-bitsy** is attested in **1938**.  The evolution from "little" to "itty" or "itsy" is ascribed to baby-talk mimicry.

> Itsy-bitsy (little bit).

- Isaac Goldberg · *The Wonder of Words. An introduction to language for Everyman* · 1938.

[**Etymonline**](http://www.etymonline.com/search?q=itsy%20bitsy), on the other hand, offers earlier attestations of some variants, and a very early 1798 attestation for "itty," the precursor to "itsy," but doesn't provide detailed citations.

> "charmingly small," 1890, from itty (baby-talk form of little) and/or bitsy. Bitsy-itsy is recorded from 1875. Itty-bitty from 1855; tiddy-itty from 1852.

It ascribes "itty" as an earlier variant of "itsy," still meaning "little," to a letter by Jane Austen in **1798**.

Both the *OED* and *Etymonline* seem to be out of date in their search for early citations.  A search of historical newspapers finds "itsy-bitsy" in its exact form in **1882**, a decade before Etymonline's attestation and several decades before the date given by the *OED*.

[image]

- **1882** - [*Fayetteville Weekly Democrat* (Fayetteville, AK )09 Feb. 5/3](https://www.newspapers.com/image/273396741) (paywall)

Likewise, "itty bitty" appears slightly earlier than attested, in **1849**.

[image]

- **1849** - [*The Arkansas Banner* (Little Rock, AK) 17 Apr. 3/5](https://www.newspapers.com/image/287730221) (paywall)

It's interesting that both of these citations appear in Arkansas newspapers, though this could be simply a result of the data available on newspapers.com.

However, dates aside, the playful baby-talk nature of this citation seems to support the etymology provided in both cases related to *baby speak*, as opposed to a borrowing from another language, as suggested in the question per Wikipedia.

Comment: Hadn't heard of newspapers.com. That's a neat site! (Minus the paywall, but  I guess old newspapers don't digitize themselves).

Comment: Impressive research. OED need you.